# Public connection string inaccessible

Tags: vb.net

I have imported my own database connection file but it doesn't like the dbConnectDBOStr string

any ideas?

```
Imports Pirelli.dbPirelli

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim strCmd As String
        Dim dbCmd As SqlCommand
        Dim oConn As SqlConnection
        Dim dbReader As SqlDataReader


        oConn = New SqlConnection(dbConnectDBOStr)
```

Connection file:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Namespace Pirelli


    Public Class dbPirelli
        'Database Server - ENABLE ONE ONLY
        Public Const strServerName As String = "[Server]"  'DEV

        Public Const dbConnectDBOStr As String = "uid=[USER];password=[PASS];database=[DB];server=" & strServerName & ";Connection Timeout=60;"

    End Class

End Namespace
```

I am getting this error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'dbConnectDBOStr' is not declared.

 Source Error:

Line 21: 
Line 22: 
Line 23:         oConn = New SqlConnection(dbConnectDBOStr)
Line 24: 
Line 25:         oConn.Open()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not dealing with an instance of your dbPirelli class, you should make your classs static and call it by namespace using:

```
Namespace Pirelli

    ' In VB a static class is called a "Module"
    Public Module dbPirelli
        'Database Server - ENABLE ONE ONLY
        Public Const strServerName As String = "[Server]"  'DEV

        Public Const dbConnectDBOStr As String = "uid=[USER];password=[PASS];database=[DB];server=" & strServerName & ";Connection Timeout=60;"

    End Module

End Namespace
```

....

```
' Since you're importing the namespace Pirelli.dbPirelli, you don't need
' to call the namespace as I had previously indicated
oConn = New SqlConnection(dbConnectDBOStr)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this doesn't work either any other ideas? it won't let me declare it as shared

Comment: @neeko: You're correct. I've been living in C# for a little too long. The syntax for a static class is different in VB. I'll make a code correction shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like:

```
oConn = New SqlConnection(dbPirelli.dbConnectDBOStr)
```